# Image is not Displaying at center in QtForm

Tags: qt

Hi I am using QLabel to show an image in QtForm.
My code goes like this

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->setMargin(5);
QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
QPixmap pixmap("/images/test.jpg");
imageLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);
imageLabel->setMask(pixmap.mask());
imageLabel->setMinimumSize(160, 160);
imageLabel->resize(500, 320);

layout->addWidget(imageLabel,0,Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignCenter);
hLayout->addItem(layout);

widget->setLayout(hLayout);

scrollArea->setWidget(widget);
setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
```

but the image is displaying at the left corner can any one suggest me to bring the image to centre to the form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got solution,

```
QPixmap pixmap("images/test.png");
imageLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);
imageLabel->setMinimumSize(160, 160);
imageLabel->resize(500, 320);
imageLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);


scrollArea->setWidget(widget);
setCentralWidget(imageLabel);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the alignment of your QLabel's content:

```
imageLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `setAlignment` function didn't work alone, then use it with `setSizePolicy`.

```
imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
imageLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```